# Expected type error in Haskell code

Tags: haskell

```
accumulate :: (a -> a) -> a -> (a -> a) -> a -> (a -> a) -> a
accumulate combiner null_value term x next n = iter x null_value
where iter x result = if x > n
                        then result
                        else iter (next x) (combiner (term x) result)
```

This runs perfectly without the type signature, but with the type signature, I keep running into this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `a -> a'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        accumulate :: (a -> a) -> a -> (a -> a) -> a -> (a -> a) -> a
      at haskell-sicp/chapter1.hs:131:15
In the expression: iter x null_value
In an equation for `accumulate':
    accumulate combiner null_value term x next n
      = iter x null_value
      where
          iter x result
            = if x > n then
                  result
              else
                  iter (next x) (combiner (term x) result)
```

I'm new to haskell, but I don't understand what is wrong with my type signature?

Comment: Try to see what is the type signature that the compiler is inferring automatically (using `:t`) and then try to understand how it fits there.

Comment: The first problem I see is that the type signature indicates that the function takes 5 arguments but the definition has 6 arguments. Also, since you are using `>` you will need an `Ord` constraint.

Comment: Thanks! That appears to have worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Near as I can tell, your `combiner` method takes two `a`'s and returns one `a`, so it should be `(a -> a -> a)`, `a` needs to be labeled an `Ord`, and you forgot to denote that the function returns an `a`. So, your actual type signature should be

```haskell
accumulate :: Ord a => (a -> a -> a) -> a -> (a -> a) -> a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```